# How to name the vertices

Tags: tikz-pgf, labels

I wrote the code in LaTeX:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1.81,-1.81) rectangle (1.81,1.81);
\draw[rotate around={134:(0,0)}] (-1.5,1.06) rectangle (1.5,-1.06);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How to write the names of outer square as ABCD and inner tilted rectangle as EFGH? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following example names the coordinates and puts labels to them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
    (-1.81,-1.81) coordinate (A)
    rectangle (1.81,1.81) coordinate (C)
    (A -| C) coordinate (B)
    (A |- C) coordinate (D)
  ;
  \draw[rotate around={134:(0,0)}]
    (-1.5,1.06) coordinate (E)
    rectangle (1.5,-1.06) coordinate (G)
    (E |- G) coordinate (F)
    (E -| G) coordinate (H)
  ;
  \path
    (A) node[below left] {A}
    (B) node[below right] {B}
    (C) node[above right] {C}
    (D) node[above left] {D}
    (E) node[below] {E}
    (F) node[right] {F}
    (G) node[above] {G}
    (H) node[left] {H}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Some fine tuning:

- The angle can be calculated and gives about 135.05° instead of 134°.
- If the protruding corners of the inner rectangle should be avoided, then
  clipping or `miter limit=1` helps, here.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro\angle{
    90
    + atan(1.06/1.5)
    + acos(1.81 / sqrt(1.5*1.5 + 1.06*1.06))
  }
  \typeout{Rotation angle: \angle}
  \draw
    (-1.81,-1.81) coordinate (A)
    rectangle (1.81,1.81) coordinate (C)
    (A -| C) coordinate (B)
    (A |- C) coordinate (D)
  ;
  \draw[rotate around={\angle:(0,0)}, miter limit=1]
    (-1.5,1.06) coordinate (E)
    rectangle (1.5,-1.06) coordinate (G)
    (E |- G) coordinate (F)
    (E -| G) coordinate (H)
  ;
  \path
    (A) node[below left] {A}
    (B) node[below right] {B}
    (C) node[above right] {C}
    (D) node[above left] {D}
    (E) node[below] {E}
    (F) node[right] {F}
    (G) node[above] {G}
    (H) node[left] {H}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with fine tuning]